# How do I store files on OneDrive that do not take up space on my hard drive?

Tags: cloud, onedrive

I have OneDrive set up on my Windows 7 laptop. I understand the basic concept, I can drag files to OneDrive and they are available on any other computer I access that OneDrive folder from. But if I have a large file on my PC, say a 10 MB video, if I copy it from My Documents to OneDrive, am I now taking up 20 MB on my C drive? If I delete it from My Documents, is it still taking up 10 MB on my C drive? What's the correct way to store a large file on OneDrive where I can access it if I need it, but it doesn't take up space?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in control panel. In Settings in the search bar lookup 'Storage' and after that click on 'Change how we free up space...' then scroll to OneDrive, you get a dropdown that says 'content will become online only if not opened for more than:' and choose the minimum time. So it'll take space for a day but then be moved to the cloud.

Then you can hit 'clean now' to start the process. That'll get you pretty close to what you want I think.

Google file stream does it much better, as it does simple cloud only storage like your talking about.

Comment: That is not an option in WIndows 7.

Comment: Files on demand might do it, I don't have a win7 to test it on but Microsoft supposedly supports it. You might have to enable in your local group policy.

Comment: Also not an option in Windows 7. Thanks for trying, every option seems to be a Windows 10 option.

Answer (score 0):

As a shortcut for one or more files which are large, and you want to clear space used by them, right click on the file in the local folder and select 'free up space'; the file will appear to have been stored locally but actually free up the local space and consume space only in the cloud. Subsequently, when you click on the local folder, only then will it stream and download back and take space on your local storage drive. once you're done using the file locally, repeat 'free up space'.